# Why CurrencyFormat isn't render in my page?

Tags: reactjs

I installed the CurrencyFormat using "npm install react-currency-format --save --force"
But CurrencyFormat is not rendering in my page. By the way, the button after CurrencyFormat is working normaly. Anyone can help me, why CurrencyFormat it isn't rendering?

```
import React from "react";
import "./Subtotal.css";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";

function Subtotal() {
  return (
    <div className="subtotal">
      <CurrencyFormat
        renderText={(value) => {
          <>
            <p>
              Subtotal (0 items): <strong>0</strong>
            </p>
            <small className="subtotal__gift">
              <input type="checkbox" />
              This order contains a gift
            </small>
          </>;
        }}
        decimalScale={2}
        value={0}
        displayType={"text"}
        thousandSeparator={true}
        prefix={"$"}
      />

      <button>Go to checkout</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Subtotal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this codesandbox link it works, You must have to return function.

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-lalande-uu0lu6?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

A small mistake you did. Add "return" inside renderText

```
 renderText={(value) => {
         return <>
            <p>
              Subtotal (0 items): <strong>0</strong>
            </p>
            <small className="subtotal__gift">
              <input type="checkbox" />
              This order contains a gift
            </small>
          </>;
        }}
```